# LookupRows loop on Entry Data extension and Lookup Data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup, loop

I have two data extensions.

Entry Data extension

```
| CONTACT_ID |
+------------+
|          1 |
|          2 |
|          3 |
+------------+
```

Lookup data extension

```
+------------+-----------+
| CONTACT_ID | PRICEPLAN |
+------------+-----------+
|          1 | a         |
|          1 | b         |
|          2 | b         |
|          3 | c         |
+------------+-----------+
```

I want to be able to look up on the CONTACT_ID and show PRICEPLAN value  in the email.
So in the email i would like the output to be:

> For CONTACT_ID = 1  show priceplan a and b

Here is my code which only shows me priceplan a.

```
%%[

SET @CONTACT_ID = CONTACT_ID
set @rows = LookupRows("LOOKUP_DATA_EXTENSION", "CONTACT_ID", @CONTACT_ID)


IF RowCount(@rows) > 0 Then

    FOR @i = 1 To RowCount(@rows) Do
    SET @row = Row(@rows,@i)
    SET @priceplan_name = Field(@row,"PRICEPLAN")

    next @i

    ENDIF

    ]%%

Your Priceplan: %%=v(@priceplan_name)=%%
```

> CURRENT OUTPUT:
>   Your Priceplan: a
>
> WANTED OUTPUT FOR CONTACT_ID = 1
>   Your Priceplan: a, b

I managed to fix it myself. Here is the code that worked.

```
%%[

SET @CONTACT_ID = CONTACT_ID
set @rows = LookupRows("LOOKUP_DATA_EXTENSION", "CONTACT_ID", @CONTACT_ID)


IF RowCount(@rows) > 0 Then

    FOR @i = 1 To RowCount(@rows) Do
    SET @row = Row(@rows,@i)
    SET @priceplan_name = Field(@row,"PRICEPLAN")

 ]%% 
Your Priceplan: %%=v(@priceplan_name)=%%<br>

%%[

    next @i

    ENDIF

    ]%%
```

Comment: Lookup function will only lookup a single value, you cannot loop it. You need to use LookupRows, as in the second code sample you provided and loop it do display all values found from 1 to rowcount - take a look here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/AMPscript401.htm

Comment: Oh great! Thank you for the information and the link! I will give it a try

Comment: And you don’t need to define @lookupValue twice - any of the two will work if it’s a column in your sendable DE

Comment: It is. I am learning new things here. Thanks!

Comment: @CodeRage I have made a new code. There is no output. Can you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You might have forgotten to set contact_Id (I don’t know if this is a personalisation string). Before you do lookuprows.

Comment: Hi @JohannesSchapdick - I tried to set the CONTACT_ID. I don't know if i did what you meant, but it didn't work. I've added it to the code.
I think it is a personalisation string, since im trying to attribute each CONTACT_ID with the PRICEPLAN attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
%%[
SET @CONTACT_ID = CONTACT_ID
set @rows = LookupRows("LOOKUP_DATA_EXTENSION", "CONTACT_ID", @

FOR @i = 1 To RowCount(@rows) DO
SET @row = Row(@rows,@i)
SET @priceplan_name = Field(@row,"PRICEPLAN")
]%%

Your Priceplan: %%=v(@priceplan_name)=%%<br>

%%[ next @i ]%%
```